# What are the status and the latest papers on Yang-Mills existence and the mass gap?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills

The Clay Millennium problem is still open. What is the recent status? Is there anybody publishing about it?

On http://www.claymath.org/millennium-problems/yang%E2%80%93mills-and-mass-gap
the last status report is from 2004 - that is a long time.

Comment: If you [google](https://google.com/search?q=QUANTUM+YANG–MILLS+THEORY+ARTHUR+JAFFE+AND+EDWARD+WITTEN) it is "Cited by 129". Some are more recent.